# stream class in windows phone 7

Tags: stream, windows-phone

I am trying to include .wav file in windows phone 7 application. But somehow , the stream class is not being recognized. any ideas why ?
also , I just dragged the wav files in the project.But isn't there an sound folder in which sound files automatically get added to ?
I have included the xna framework and the xna.framework.audio libraries.please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the format of the file has to be the following:

```
Codec: Microsoft PCM Format
Sample Rate: 11025
Channels: 1(Mono) or 2(Stereo)
```

Here is a short tutorial with an example on [playing wav files on Windows Phone 7](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2010/09/29/playing-wav-files-on-windows-phone-7.aspx).